# Not able to connect to mongodb Atlas cluster from nodejs(express) simple app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ubuntu-18.04

I created a simple node and express app. I am trying to connect to my cluster on atlas but it always fails to connect.

Following is my index.js file :

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var cors = require("cors");

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// create express app
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const url = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster1-n60yg.mongodb.net/test";

//Connecting to the database
mongoose
  .connect(url, {
    dbName: "testdb"
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...", err);
    process.exit();
  });

// define a simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "this will br crud" });
});

// listen for requests
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
});
```

After about 1-2 minutes after I run the code, this error is thrown:

```
Could not connect to the database. Exiting now... { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster1-shard-00-00-n60yg.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection timed out]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/nikhil/Documents/node-graphql-mongo-crud/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:431:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at connect (/home/nikhil/Documents/node-graphql-mongo-crud/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:557:14)
    at makeConnection (/home/nikhil/Documents/node-graphql-mongo-crud/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:39:11)
    at callback (/home/nikhil/Documents/node-graphql-mongo-crud/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:261:5)
    at TLSSocket.err (/home/nikhil/Documents/node-graphql-mongo-crud/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:286:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:422:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

This code works in a sandbox (i.e. It is connecting successfully). But for some reason, I can't connect it from my laptop (I am using Ubuntu 18.04). 
I am behind a corporate proxy. But I tried this with mobile data (cellular network) and it still doesn't work.
I have already whitelisted all IPs (0.0.0.0/0) in Network access setting in mongodb atlas.

I saw the [docs](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/setup-cluster-security/#network-and-firewall-requirements) and found this in "Network and Firewall requirements":

> If you use a whitelist on your firewall for network ports, open ports >27015 to 27017 to TCP and UDP traffic on Atlas hosts. This grants your >applications access to databases stored on Atlas.

Is this step is what I am missing? 
Please suggest solutions to this problem.

**EDIT**
I got it working on mobile data but still can't connect through corporate proxy. Any working solutions?

Comment: Would this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48418807/11330560

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using correct username and password in the query, Also it looks like your's database name is testdb and in the query make sure you replace "test" with "testdb"

```
const url = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster1-n60yg.mongodb.net/testdb";
```

Comment: I have checked the credentials, they are correct. Also, this edit in the url gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code and ran against my own mongodb instance and changed the url as

```
const url = "mongodb+srv://admin:PASSWORD@cluster1-n60yg.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true";
```

and it worked and it printed the output "**Successfully connected to the database**".

Comment: Exactly...This code works on sandbox. So I guess there might be something wrong with my system...it's just I can't figure out what!

Comment: Please confirm you're using latest versions of packages

Answer (score 0):

I whitelisted my IP address, (found out it had changed earlier) or you can just go on and accept any random IP.

I also placed the connection inside an asynchronous function.

Code:

```
// ======================== db configurations===========================//
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const connectDB = async () => {
    mongoose.connect(db.url, db.options);
    console.log('DB Connected....');
};

connectDB();
```

hope this helps, happy hacking!